# Не переведено "Edit pending" на странице создания описания метки

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, метки, предлагаемые-правки

[вот тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/google-protobuf/info), например, (пока еще)

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Добавил перевод:

- https://ru.traducir.win/strings/14668

Будет на сайте в свежих сборках. Текущая  rev 2021.1.27.38425