# Странная ошибка "Сообщение дублирует ХХХХХ"

Tags: обсуждение, дефект

Создавал [предыдущий вопрос](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/11328/%D0%9D%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BE-edit-pending-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B8) и вылезло странное сообщение об ошибке, что он дублирует [другой](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/11133/%D0%92%D0%BE-%D0%B2%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%8F%D1%89%D0%B8%D1%85-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D1%83%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D0%B1-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мало того, что не дублирует, там общего только обе метки. После добавления текста сообщение исчезло, но сам факт его появления вызывает недоумение. Что за алгоритм такой глупый?

Comment: в обоих случаях речь про отсутствие перевода

Comment: @Grundy так тут десятки сообщений об отсутствии перевода. Они же не дублируют друг друга. И непонятно, почему сообщение с текстом не вызывает такой ошибки, а просто со скриншотом вызывает.

Comment: Это при нажатии кнопки "Задайте ваш вопрос" возникло? А какое наполнение вопроса было при этом? И я что-то не могу найти сообщение с заголовком "Во входящих не переведено уведомление об отмене серийного голосования".

Comment: @αλεχολυτ Да, после того, как нажал на "Задайте ваш вопрос". Тот, другой, вопрос удален, я дал на него [ссылку в первом предложении](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/11133/%D0%92%D0%BE-%D0%B2%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%8F%D1%89%D0%B8%D1%85-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D1%83%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D0%B1-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F).

Answer (score 2):

Проверка на одинаковость сообщений имеет скорее всего какой-то более хитрый критерий соответвия нежели полное совпадение. В данном случае для анализа было немного текста (который, вероятно, просто был проигнорирован в алгоритме из-за недостаточного объёма),  картинка и метки. Метки совпали; картинки, скорее всего, вовсе не анализируются, может быть только факт их наличия/отсутствия; в заголовке есть совпадающие слова. Ну и ключевой момент, что вопросы заданы одним участником и старый удалён автором. Условно, автор мог задать вопрос, потом передумать и удалить его, а затем через N времени задать снова, тут система его и предложила как дубликат. Имхо, вполне логично.

Так что я не думаю, что здесь имеет место какой-то дефект, скорее всего, так задумано.

Comment: да странно, что по совпадению двух-трех общеупотребительных слов система не дает отправить сообщение. Но хоть хорошо, что обойти эти систему проще простого :)

Comment: @Эникейщик допускаю, что если объём нового (и/или старого) сообщения был бы несколько больше, вердикта о дублировании бы не было вынесено.